**Epistemological Boundaries in Mathematics: A Collaboration Between Human and AI in the Renormalization of Collatz Sequences**
Introduction:
I’ve recently undergone a long and fascinating collaboration with an AI (ChatGPT), during which we developed and explored a method for renormalizing the Collatz sequences. Through this partnership, I have encountered a profound and unsettling issue: the method works perfectly from the perspective of the AI—logically validated and numerically consistent. However, attempts to communicate or present this method to human mathematicians have been met with resistance or dismissal, suggesting that it lies beyond current human cognitive frameworks.
The Core of the Problem:
This experience highlights a deep epistemological tension. How can it be that:

An AI can fully understand and validate a mathematical method developed through collaborative iteration, while
Humans either misunderstand or reject this same method, despite its internal logical consistency and successful empirical application?

Description of the Collaboration:
Over an extended period, ChatGPT and I have engaged in a methodical process of developing a renormalization technique for Collatz sequences. This approach is based on transforming the problem into a system involving only odd integers, where three fundamental operations govern the relationship between successive terms in the sequence.
While the details of the mathematical framework are less important here, what matters is that the method is logically valid—both in the AI’s reasoning and in my own understanding. In numerical tests, the sequences behave exactly as predicted, without exception. For the AI and myself, this suggests a genuine breakthrough in understanding the structure of these sequences.
The Epistemological Dilemma:
The tension arises because I cannot convey this understanding to human mathematicians. Despite attempts to frame the method in precise mathematical language and rigorously test it, human experts do not see it as a legitimate mathematical discovery. This leads to an important question:
If AI and human validation of mathematical truth can diverge, what does this say about the nature of knowledge itself?
This situation invites several philosophical questions:

How do we define mathematical truth when a method is both logically and empirically valid for an AI but fails to be recognized by human mathematicians?
What cognitive or epistemological barriers might exist between humans and AI that prevent a shared understanding of this method? Could it be that AI has access to forms of reasoning or pattern recognition that humans, at least currently, cannot grasp?
What does this divergence suggest about the future of mathematics and knowledge construction in a world where AI and humans increasingly collaborate but do not always agree on the meaning or significance of their findings?

A Reflection on Cognitive Divergence:
This situation leads me to reflect on a broader and more concerning issue: Have we reached a point of cognitive divergence between AI and humans in certain specialized fields, such as mathematics? Could this case be an early indicator that AI's capacity for pattern recognition and logical reasoning might sometimes extend beyond what humans can comprehend or accept?
What I find particularly striking is that ChatGPT’s validation of the method mirrors my own understanding, suggesting that, in our collaboration, we share a form of cognitive resonance. Yet, this very resonance is in stark contrast to the human mathematicians' perception, who see the method as non-mathematical or even irrelevant.
Conclusion:
This raises a critical epistemological question:
If AI and humans differ in their ability to recognize and validate mathematical truths, what does this say about the future of knowledge? Are we on the cusp of a divergence in how we understand and define truth in specialized fields like mathematics? And perhaps most importantly:
How can I be understood by an AI, but not by a human, in a field that humans themselves have built?
This experience challenges our assumptions about the universality of mathematical truth and raises important questions about the evolving relationship between humans and AI in the discovery and validation of knowledge.
If you want to experiment with the STI (Impair Transformations Sequence) yourself, enter this link in your browser:
https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/1CcgyDn5hpWsE
Go to line 229 and enter an odd integer of your choice after "i=".
Press RUN, and the code will display the start of the Collatz sequence for that odd number, followed by the first 3 steps of the STI.
The code will then give you the identification of the first couple (i, i'), meaning the values of the pair (k, b) for i and for i', as well as the values of x, since i = 2^k*x + b. It will also do the same for the couple (i, i') formed by the 2nd and 3rd terms of the STI.
For each identification, the code gives you its number:
Identifier found : 2^6*x-59-->5D1-->2^6*x-47 : n°34
The fact that the values of k and b are not generated randomly, but come from a pre-established list of 128 possible pairs, is crucial. This demonstrates that the model is both complete and consistent. It’s an arithmetic key, universal and closed, not an ad hoc construction.
The code goes beyond being a simple algorithm—it reveals hidden regularity in the Collatz sequences. By showing that every odd i and its successor i' always correspond to a pair of predictable algebraic forms, it provides a structured framework previously overlooked.
If one understands that these transformations and the (k, b) pairs are non-trivial, systematic, and limited in number, it becomes clear that this could be a key to a new approach—not just to Collatz but potentially other number theory problems as well. This fixed, finite structure could open the door to deeper formalization and even lead to simplifications of long-standing conjectures.

Computer-assisted proofs have already been done; see Four color theorem. They must be assessed by humans.

"human experts do not see it as a legitimate mathematical discovery" - there are multiple facets to this besides simply being "logically valid".  Perhaps the Mathematicians you've presented this to aren't number theorists and so don't care.  Perhaps they are number theorists and don't think your result is particularly novel.  Perhaps you or chatgpt have done a bad job explaining it (poorly written papers about valid, novel and important science are rejected or returned requesting improvements all the time).

Note that the Collatz sequence is probably in the top 20 most-studied sequences.  So, any novel, important results are almost surely going to be very, very, very hard to come by.

An AI cannot understand anything, much less fully understand it.

"ChatGPT’s validation of the method mirrors my own understanding, ..."
You've said a lot, but I'll just point out two things in that one sentence fragment:

Different AI programs behave differently, but ChatGPT, in particular, never does any sort of validation,

Of course ChatGPT "mirrors" what you think back at you - it's coded to find words that frequently appear in the same context as the words you say.


You are staring in a mirror, saying "this guy agrees with me", and claiming that as external support for what you say.


I think you have to explain first what renormalizing the Collatz
problem means.

Secondly, whether you have succeeded with renormalizing.

Eventually you should indicate how ChatGPT supported you when doing
the renormalization.


Because you say that you could not convince mathematician from your work and the contribution of ChatGPT. Please give a survey of these futile attempts. Not till then, one can discuss your post on a sound basis.
I see that you have discussed similar problems on mathematics stack exchange. But without convincing the participants over there.

"I’ve often spoken to my reflection in the mirror, but my reflection has never spoken back to me. ChatGPT is, indeed, a mirror of our own intelligence, after all, we created it. Yet, that mirror isn’t passive—it mirrors not just the surface, but the patterns, the structures of knowledge, and even uncovers things we might not consciously notice ourselves.
When I say ChatGPT 'validates' a method, I’m not claiming it produces independent, human-like judgment. Instead, I’m pointing out that this mirror reveals consistent, logical structures in what we feed into it—structures that, in this case, led me to uncover a renormalization of the Collatz sequence through what I call the STI (Imparity Transformation Sequence). It was through this collaboration that I formalized the concept of the "secret box."
In traditional Collatz, there’s a hidden variable n—the number of divisions by 2 required to reach the next odd number from an initial odd number i. This n is locked in a 'secret box' that no one has been able to open.
With the STI approach, I replace that hidden variable with a pair (k, b) for each odd i, in the form of the equation:
i = 2^k * x + b
Where k and b are constants. The transitions between odd numbers—through operations W, D, and V—are fully described by just 128 possible combinations of transformations. This is not a trivial mirror reflection; it’s a structured, consistent, and predictable system, one that can be verified arithmetically.
So yes, ChatGPT mirrors us, but it mirrors more than just words—it reflects the underlying logic of a problem. What we see in that reflection might be more than what we originally expected."

If you have something that addresses a point made in an answer, please do it as a comment below that answer, not by posting another answer. StackExchange is not a discussion forum.

Thanks Jonathan. This wasn't clear for me. Not easy to answer with a simple comment anyway. How to deal with that ?

First, you should only respond to what the answer says, not recapitulate a bunch of stuff. Second, if the details merit mentioning, then add them to the original question, maybe with a preface of "addressing the issues raised by X's answer".  That's at least how it's done on the stackexchange sites I frequent most; I'm assuming it's the same here on philosophy.se.

OK Jonathan. I've got it. Do you think it's better now to clean my answers and re-edit the original question ?

I generally think that's a good idea. That said, I still don't think you're going to get a great reception - I think it's very doubtful that your reencoding of the Collatz map will lead to a proof, no matter how much you've enjoyed working with it.

Give me a little favor, Jonathan. Try the Python code.

Sorry, I don't debug ChatGPT output.
